# Algorithm to distribute according to weights, with unknown total of items, guaranteeing good distribution?

Tags: algorithm, distribution, probability

I want to distribute tokens into 3 slots.

Each slot has some weight: maybe 50% of tokens should go into the first slot, 30% should go into the second slot, 20% into the third slot.

I don't know the total number of tokens – they keep on coming. I may get 1000 tokens to distribute at noon, I get another 300 at 1 p.m. and so on, unpredictably. At any point in time, the tokens I have received so far should be distributed as well as possible according to the weights.

One solution is to distribute by probabilities. I roll a 100-sided die for each token. If the result is 1–50, the token goes in slot 1. A result of 51–80 mean slot 2, a result of 81–100 mean slot 3.

But this means that it's not impossible (only improbable) that every single token ends up in slot 3, for example.

I want to guarantee that when I've received a total of 100 tokens, then exactly 50 of them will be in slot 1. When I've received 1000 tokens, exactly 500 should be in slot 1.

What is a good algorithm for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the error in each slot according to what the ideal distribution is. Always insert a token into the slot with the most error. If two or more slots are tied, insert into a random one among them.

The error is the difference between the expected number of tokens (tokens added * ratio) and the actual number of tokens.

This way you will always minimize error, and there will be no error if the tokens are able to be distributed exactly.

Demonstration code (this inserts into the first slot if there is equal amount of error instead of distributing randomly):

```
import random

tokens_in_slots = [0, 0, 0]
slot_distributions = [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]

def add_token():
    num_tokens = sum(tokens_in_slots)
    if not num_tokens:
        #first token can go anywhere
        tokens_in_slots[random.randint(0,2)] += 1
        return
    expected_tokens = [num_tokens*distr for distr in slot_distributions]
    errors = [expected - actual
              for expected, actual in zip(expected_tokens, tokens_in_slots)]
    most_error = max(enumerate(errors), key=lambda (i,e): e)
    tokens_in_slots[most_error[0]] += 1

def add_and_print(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        add_token()
        print sum(tokens_in_slots), tokens_in_slots
```

Result:

```
>>> add_and_print(100)
1 [0, 0, 1]
2 [1, 0, 1]
3 [1, 1, 1]
4 [2, 1, 1]
5 [2, 2, 1]
6 [3, 2, 1]
7 [3, 2, 2]
8 [4, 2, 2]
9 [4, 3, 2]
10 [5, 3, 2]
11 [6, 3, 2]
12 [6, 4, 2]
13 [6, 4, 3]
14 [7, 4, 3]
15 [7, 5, 3]
16 [8, 5, 3]
17 [8, 5, 4]
18 [9, 5, 4]
19 [9, 6, 4]
20 [10, 6, 4]
21 [11, 6, 4]
22 [11, 7, 4]
23 [11, 7, 5]
24 [12, 7, 5]
25 [12, 8, 5]
26 [13, 8, 5]
27 [13, 8, 6]
28 [14, 8, 6]
29 [14, 9, 6]
30 [15, 9, 6]
31 [16, 9, 6]
32 [16, 10, 6]
33 [16, 10, 7]
34 [17, 10, 7]
35 [17, 11, 7]
36 [18, 11, 7]
37 [18, 11, 8]
38 [19, 11, 8]
39 [19, 12, 8]
40 [20, 12, 8]
41 [21, 12, 8]
42 [21, 13, 8]
43 [21, 13, 9]
44 [22, 13, 9]
45 [22, 14, 9]
46 [23, 14, 9]
47 [23, 14, 10]
48 [24, 14, 10]
49 [24, 15, 10]
50 [25, 15, 10]
51 [26, 15, 10]
52 [26, 16, 10]
53 [26, 16, 11]
54 [27, 16, 11]
55 [27, 17, 11]
56 [28, 17, 11]
57 [28, 17, 12]
58 [29, 17, 12]
59 [29, 18, 12]
60 [30, 18, 12]
61 [31, 18, 12]
62 [31, 19, 12]
63 [31, 19, 13]
64 [32, 19, 13]
65 [32, 20, 13]
66 [33, 20, 13]
67 [33, 20, 14]
68 [34, 20, 14]
69 [34, 21, 14]
70 [35, 21, 14]
71 [36, 21, 14]
72 [36, 22, 14]
73 [36, 22, 15]
74 [37, 22, 15]
75 [37, 23, 15]
76 [38, 23, 15]
77 [38, 23, 16]
78 [39, 23, 16]
79 [39, 24, 16]
80 [40, 24, 16]
81 [41, 24, 16]
82 [41, 25, 16]
83 [41, 25, 17]
84 [42, 25, 17]
85 [42, 26, 17]
86 [43, 26, 17]
87 [43, 26, 18]
88 [44, 26, 18]
89 [44, 27, 18]
90 [45, 27, 18]
91 [46, 27, 18]
92 [46, 28, 18]
93 [46, 28, 19]
94 [47, 28, 19]
95 [47, 29, 19]
96 [48, 29, 19]
97 [48, 29, 20]
98 [49, 29, 20]
99 [49, 30, 20]
100 [50, 30, 20]
```

Results for

```
tokens_in_slots = [0, 0, 0, 0]
slot_distributions = [0.8, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05]
```

:

```
>>> add_and_print(100)
1 [0, 0, 1, 0]
2 [1, 0, 1, 0]
3 [2, 0, 1, 0]
4 [3, 0, 1, 0]
5 [3, 1, 1, 0]
6 [4, 1, 1, 0]
7 [5, 1, 1, 0]
8 [6, 1, 1, 0]
9 [7, 1, 1, 0]
10 [7, 1, 1, 1]
11 [8, 1, 1, 1]
12 [9, 1, 1, 1]
13 [10, 1, 1, 1]
14 [11, 1, 1, 1]
15 [11, 2, 1, 1]
16 [12, 2, 1, 1]
17 [13, 2, 1, 1]
18 [14, 2, 1, 1]
19 [15, 2, 1, 1]
20 [16, 2, 1, 1]
21 [17, 2, 1, 1]
22 [17, 3, 1, 1]
23 [18, 3, 1, 1]
24 [19, 3, 1, 1]
25 [20, 3, 1, 1]
26 [20, 3, 2, 1]
27 [21, 3, 2, 1]
28 [22, 3, 2, 1]
29 [23, 3, 2, 1]
30 [23, 3, 2, 2]
31 [24, 3, 2, 2]
32 [25, 3, 2, 2]
33 [26, 3, 2, 2]
34 [27, 3, 2, 2]
35 [27, 4, 2, 2]
36 [28, 4, 2, 2]
37 [29, 4, 2, 2]
38 [30, 4, 2, 2]
39 [31, 4, 2, 2]
40 [32, 4, 2, 2]
41 [33, 4, 2, 2]
42 [33, 5, 2, 2]
43 [34, 5, 2, 2]
44 [35, 5, 2, 2]
45 [36, 5, 2, 2]
46 [36, 5, 3, 2]
47 [37, 5, 3, 2]
48 [38, 5, 3, 2]
49 [39, 5, 3, 2]
50 [39, 5, 3, 3]
51 [40, 5, 3, 3]
52 [41, 5, 3, 3]
53 [42, 5, 3, 3]
54 [43, 5, 3, 3]
55 [43, 6, 3, 3]
56 [44, 6, 3, 3]
57 [45, 6, 3, 3]
58 [46, 6, 3, 3]
59 [47, 6, 3, 3]
60 [48, 6, 3, 3]
61 [49, 6, 3, 3]
62 [49, 7, 3, 3]
63 [50, 7, 3, 3]
64 [51, 7, 3, 3]
65 [52, 7, 3, 3]
66 [52, 7, 4, 3]
67 [53, 7, 4, 3]
68 [54, 7, 4, 3]
69 [55, 7, 4, 3]
70 [55, 7, 4, 4]
71 [56, 7, 4, 4]
72 [57, 7, 4, 4]
73 [58, 7, 4, 4]
74 [59, 7, 4, 4]
75 [59, 8, 4, 4]
76 [60, 8, 4, 4]
77 [61, 8, 4, 4]
78 [62, 8, 4, 4]
79 [63, 8, 4, 4]
80 [64, 8, 4, 4]
81 [65, 8, 4, 4]
82 [65, 9, 4, 4]
83 [66, 9, 4, 4]
84 [67, 9, 4, 4]
85 [68, 9, 4, 4]
86 [68, 9, 5, 4]
87 [69, 9, 5, 4]
88 [70, 9, 5, 4]
89 [71, 9, 5, 4]
90 [71, 9, 5, 5]
91 [72, 9, 5, 5]
92 [73, 9, 5, 5]
93 [74, 9, 5, 5]
94 [75, 9, 5, 5]
95 [75, 10, 5, 5]
96 [76, 10, 5, 5]
97 [77, 10, 5, 5]
98 [78, 10, 5, 5]
99 [79, 10, 5, 5]
100 [80, 10, 5, 5]
```

Comment: That's a great and simple way to describe the problem. Thanks! I think I'll try something along these lines.

Comment: Implemented it in Ruby so I could toy with it: https://gist.github.com/3276573#file_claudiu.rb

Answer (score 0):

The solution that springs to my mind:

Give every slot a computed score. Put the token in the slot with the highest score. If more than one share that score, I don't care whether we pick the first one or a random one.

The computed score would be calculated something like the following Ruby/pseudo-code:

```
# Example values
# Floats to avoid integer division
slot_1_weight = 50.0
total_weight  = 100.0
slot_1_tokens = 2.0
total_tokens  = 3.0

if total_tokens == 0 || total_weight == 0 || slot_1_tokens
  # Avoid division by zero.
  slot_1_score = slot_1_weight
else
  expected_distribution = slot_1_weight/total_weight
  actual_distribution = slot_1_tokens/total_tokens
  slot_1_score  = slot_1_weight * (expected_distribution/actual_distribution)
end
```

So when expected and actual match, the score is the original weight. If expected is too high, the weight is scaled down. If expected is too low, the weight is scaled up.